# What happens when one of the 2 DC's goes down

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

There are 2 Domain Controllers running Windows Server 2003 x64 R2.

The installed roles of DC1 (10.0.0.1) are: File Server, Print Server, Application Server, DNS Server and of course Active Directory. The FSMO Roles are handled by DC1 as well, all five of them (RID, PDC, Infastructure, Schema Master, Domain Naming Master).

THe installed roles of DC2 (10.0.0.11) are: File Server, Application Server, DNS Server and Active Directory. The FSMO roles are assigned to DC1 so the DC2 FSMO roles point to the DC1.

Both Domain Controllers are Global Catalogs.

I am examing the scenarios where:

1. DC1 goes down due to hardware/software problem but gets back online after few hours/days
2. DC1 goes down completely with no chance to get back online ever again
3. DC2 goes down due to hardware/software problem but gets back online after few hours/days
4. DC2 goes down completely with no chance to get back online ever again

Apart from the two main DC's there is another Windows Server 2003 x64 R2 with no roles installed sitting there unplugged just in case of a disaster.

What I want to know is the best practice possible for each scenario and what steps (detailed, if you mind) should I follow to achieve all. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't know if this a scenario question or an actual production network, but it's generally bad practise to put anything but the Domain Controller role on a DC. It's also bad SF practise to ask "please provide teh tutorial". If you have looked for an answer and need help clarifying it, that's fine, but asking users to do everything isn't quite fair.

Comment: 2 and 4 are 'easily' solved by just rebuilding the relevant server from your documentation on new hardware surely ?

Comment: No no, I wasn't asking for tutorials from anybody. I can google for that. :)
As steps I refer to the steps/actions (1, 2, 3, 4,..) I have to do to each scenario. For example:
Step #: Seize the FSMO roles to the DC2
Step #: Clean the metadata
.. and so on.
I never asked for a full tutorial. Sorry if for the misunderstanding.

Comment: "most critical" fsmo roles are PDC and then RID. Without a PDC you start getting errors with Kerberos tickets, password replications, etc... In any case you can use the "seize" option since there is always a transfer try before performing a seize operation.

Comment: @lain:  In 2 and 4 I'm assuming that no spare parts are available for the server in order to get back online or in case it's substitued by a new one.

Comment: @SantiFdezMunoz: So, seize the FSMO roles is one of the first steps I should do in all scenarios in order to avoid errors and potential problems?

Comment: @user201420 in scenarios 2 and 4 seize is the only option. In the other scenarios it depends since transfering a fsmo role depends on communication between DCs so if downtime is a few hours, its better just waiting for the FSMO, but if downtime is a few days it highly depends on which do you understand for "few days", but in any case if you perform a seize operation that DC should never get online again, so it would be better not to recover the Computer Object for the DC and perform a metadata cleanup before the deployment of a new DC with the same name.